# Read access violation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing some C++ code to create an item of a class i have created inside a vector of another class. I seem to be able to create the items inside the vector but when i try to read a variable of the item inside the vector i get the error

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Right_data was 0x8.
```

inside the document xstring.

I think it might have something to do with me not actually creating each team inside the vector.

the code i have written that is relavent is

```
    for (int x = 1; x <= mainLeague.getNumTeams(); x++) {
        std::cout << "please enter the name of team " << x << ":";
        std::getline(std::cin, currLine);
        parsed = parseText(currLine, &posResponsesTeamNames);
        if (parsed == 2) {
            prepForEnd();
            return 1;
        }
        else if (parsed == 0) goto enterTeamNames;
        mainLeague.createTeam(currLine);
    }
    std::cout << mainLeague.getName(5);
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include "team.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class league
{
    std::vector<team*> teams;
    int numTeams, numInitTeams = 0;
    const float sysCon = 0.5;
public:
    league(int a);
    int getNumTeams();
    void initVector(int numTeams);
    void createTeam(std::string name);
    std::string getName(int num);
};
```

```
void league::createTeam(std::string name)
{
    if (numInitTeams < teams.size()) {
        team currTeam = team::team(name);
        teams.at(numInitTeams) = &currTeam;
        numInitTeams;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "error max amount of teams already created";
    }
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include<string>

class team
{
    float RD;
    int rating;
    std::string name;
public:
    team(std::string name);
    team();
    std::string getName();
};
```

```
std::string team::getName()
{
    return team::name;
}
```

Comment: `team currTeam = team::team(name); teams.at(numInitTeams) = &currTeam;` is setting `teams` to store pointers to a local variable that is destroyed when it goes out of scope soon after the assignment, leaving the vector with a dangling pointer.  Why are you storing *pointers* to `team` objects (`std::vector<team*>`), instead of storing *actual* `team` objects (`std::vector<team>`)?

Comment: Thanks i was trying to do it without a vector before this and was trying to use pointers. I think that is just due to me not fully changing my code. I will try and rewrite the code with the vector just using the team class and  not using pointers. EDIT: it works fine if i just use variable instead of pointers +1